# How to find out user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :comments, :through => :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

How I can fetch the user name that make a comments?

Comment: There seems to be no connection between a comment and a user, assuming other than the post author can comment on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  delegate :user, to :post
end
```

Then in your code you can access

```
@comment.user
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Comment-belongs-to-User association:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This way you can fetch the commentor quite easily:

```
@comment.user
```

Comment: But I need to fetch user from above association. please someone help me.

Comment: Given a `@post = Post.first`, you can iterate through the comments like so: `@post.comments.each {|c| '%s: %s' % [c.user, c.body] }`. For performance reasons, you could use `@post = Post.includes(comments: :user).first` to avoid N+1 queries.